# Lost added DLLs when I pushed my project to Azure Dev Ops repository

Tags: c#, dll, reference, sharedpreferences

I created a `C#` project targeted `.net 5`, this project depends on a three `DLLs`.
Firstly, I added those `DLLs` as a project reference in my main project.

**The problem:**
When I pushed my project to Azure DevOps repository and **when I cloned the repository from another computer, I saw some errors told me that my project doesn't contains some classes and methods** (those classes and methods are in the DLLs)

**Note:**
I don't want to add these `DLLs` every time manually.

**Please how can I fix this issue?**
I wanna the DLLs stay with the project even if push it (project) to a repository.

Comment: See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you sir, I tried to added the dlls into a folder inside the project and everythigs works fine
Is this method good or not ?

Comment: If the .dll's aren't available on NuGet, and don't require a platform installer or GAC installation, then it's probably fine.  IMO it's important that you can build after cloning, so if you have to put dependencies in the repo, it's fine.

Comment: Ok massive thanks sir